# How to get all rows of jsf or PrimeFaces datatable programmatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, uicomponents

I am using an datatable and every row has a selectonemenu as an column.

There is a button on my page.When it is clicked,i want to check every rows of datatable,find the selected item of selectone menu and make some database stuff depending on this selected value.

Is there a easier way without using programmatical way or any solution to my codes?

Here is my code:

Here I just tried to find a outputtext,but it did not work.

```
private DataTable myTable//primefaces datatable;



for ( UIComponent row : myTable.getChildren()) {
            HtmlOutputText  a=  (HtmlOutputText) row.findComponent("bname");

            System.out.println("click"+a.getValue());       

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind selected values of selectionmen to a map.

```
<p:dataTable .... rowIndexVar="index">
   ... somwhere in column
   <p:selectOneMenu value="#{backingBean.values[index]}" >
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the value attribute of datatable to a list of POJOs. The table column corresponds to the POJO member.

```
public class MyPOJO{
public String column1;
public String column2;
public String column3;
public String column4;
    //setters and getters here ....
}

@ManagedBean(name="beanDetails")
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
public List<MyPOJO> list_POJO;
private HashMap<String,String> fieldValues;
    //setters and getters here ....
}

<p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{beanDetails.list_POJO}" var="dataItem"> 
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputLabel value="Column 1" />
    </f:facet>

   <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{dataItem.column1}" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="input">
              <p:selectOneMenu id="relevance" value="#{dataItem.column1}">
                     <f:selectItems value="#{beanDetails.fieldValues}"/>
              </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
   </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
   .... 
   ....
</p:dataTable>  

<p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{beanDetails.submitDetails}"/>
```

And in submitDetails, you can traverse through the datatable records using list_POJO.